# Get file translation mode of stdout

Tags: file-io, console-application, windows-console, crt, widechar

Function [`int _setmode(int, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019) allows to switch `stdout` among ASCII and UTF (wide) modes.

**Is there a function to read the current translation mode of `stdout`?** Something like `_getmode`? In C# there is the [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=netframework-4.8) property.

I'd like to use it for functions that can temporarily change the mode and then set back the original mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019#return-value):

> Return Value
>
> If successful, returns the previous translation mode.

Using the return value allows to set back the original value.